# (Help With Proof) Sum of 3 or more consec integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I am working on a proof to try and describe the numbers
that can be written as a sum of 3 or more positive consecutive integers
so far I have come up with a formula 
S = kn + k(k-1)/2 where n>=1 and k>=3

But I am not sure where to go from here I need to now show which types of numbers will be satisfied by the equation but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 0):

$k+(k+1)+\dots+(k+n-1)=\frac{n(2k+n-1)}{2}$.

If $n$ is odd you get all of the multiples of $n$ and if $n$ is even you get all of the numbers of the form $(n/2)\times k$ where $k$ is odd.

If $n$ has an odd prime factor $p$ then it is a sum of $p$ consecutive integers.

If is an even power of $2:n=2^a$ or $n=-2^a$ then $n$ is the sum of $2^{a+1}$ consecutive integers.

So the only ones that are not of this form are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Any integer $s \ge 2$ will do, with $k = 2 s$ and $n = 1-s$.  That is,

$$ (1-s) + (2-s) + \ldots + s = s$$

Or do you want a sum of consecutive **positive** integers?

Comment: positive integers